# how to run a python script present in the cluster node file system in Amazon EMR

Tags: python, hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

I am looking for ways to run a `python script` against an `EMR cluster`. I went through some documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html) but they only list data source as `S3`, or `DynamoDB`. How can I execute a `python script` which is not present in these but is stored in `file system (cluster node file system)`?

If there is no way to execute a `python script` present in the file system against a `EMR cluster` then what are my other options to execute the `python script` against `EMR cluster`?

Comment: Where is you data? on your computer, on the cluster node filesystem or on HDFS?

Comment: @mr0re1 my data is on cluster node filesystem.

Comment: Check this article http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: @mr0re1 Where does it mentions about executing python scripts in Amazon EMR?

Comment: I've assumed that you want to run Python MapReduce script. If you only want to execute script you need to add script-runner step:    Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=["/tmp/script.py", ... other arguments]. Don't forget to make executable and add shebang "#!/usr/bin/python2".  More information here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html

Comment: @mr0re1 I had went through the above post but it executes the script which is present on the `S3`. I want to execute the script which is not on S3 but is present on `cluster node filesystem`.

Comment: You can pass a local path as a first argument to the script-runner step. Take a look at step description at my previous comment.